# Automatically run build on file change

Tags: build

Is there a way to automatically trigger a rebuild after changing a file in my project?
I'd like to do something similar to SASS, which watches a directory of scss files and compiles new css files instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variety of good build systems which have different dependencies and requirements.

Some samples from "old school" builders are: [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant), [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29)

If you building web app, or just in case using nodejs you may try javascript based builders, just small list of names: [Bower](https://github.com/bower/bower), [Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt), [GearJS](http://gearjs.org/), [Shifter (YUI3)](https://github.com/yui/shifter).

So just measure your needs/abilities and based on that measurements choose whatever is better suite.